# In MS Excel (Office 2016), how do I select a column NEXT to the highest value?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, ms-office, excel-2016

For example, I have 3 sets of values

| Names | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | 500 |
| Cat | 300 |
| Mouse | 350 |

I want to simply compare the values, and show the "Name" of whichever value is the highest.

I have tried it with a simple IF(A>B;IF(B>C;(IF(C>A);C;A);B;C;B), but the statement fails as soon as the first "False" value is reached.

There MUST be a better way, can someone please help me find it?!
:-)

Comment: What if there's a tie? If there can't be, then `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft 365:

```
=@SORTBY(A2:A4,B2:B4,-1)
```

With previous versions of Excel you could try `LOOKUP()` to return the last name where the value is equal to the max:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:B4=MAX(B2:B4)),A2:A4)
```

Or a combination of `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` to return the 1st name:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(MAX(B2:B4),B2:B4,0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should've mentioned - I am using MS Office 2016

Comment: @VikrantSrivastava, I added an alternative option.